# ionic XHR failed loading: POST

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/authproject/public/api/auth/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8101' is therefore not allowed access.
ionic.bundle.js:15567 XHR failed loading: POST
```

Could someone tell me how do I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try installing [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) on your browser and enabling it ?

[image]

Comment: I added Allow-Control-Allow-Origin but I don't enable it, how I can enable it in my browser

Comment: Check the image that I added @Sondes

Comment: Hello, while I am using `ionic serve`, from my browser it is working fine. But while I am using a device, it is not working. Any way to solve it?